# Сколько будет запросов?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Добрый день!
Уточните, пожалуйста, сколько будет SQL запросов два или один ?

```
INSERT INTO test (id, test2_id) (null, (SELECT id FROM test2))
```

Comment: Будет запрос, а внутри него подзапрос. Это два или один? .-.

Comment: от вас на сервер будет один запрос, а как на сервере будет уже не важно

Comment: В итоге, сколько будет выполнено SQL запросов?

Comment: судя по вопросу вам еще рано вникать в такие детали, поэтому можете смело считать, что будет выполнен всего один запрос. В терминах "запроса" этого не объяснить. Запрос один, но сервер БД сначала выполнит подзапрос, а потом полученный результат будет вставлять в таблицу. Все это будет выполнено на стороне сервера, поэтому вы даже не узнаете что именно происходит. Фактически, серверу ничего не мешает выполнить подзапрос несколько десятков раз, а потом сотни раз вставлять/откатывать изменения. Для вас все равно это будет одним запросом

Comment: результат `SELECT id FROM test2` вам не придет, а значит и не вы посылаете эти данные на сервер для вставки. От вас на сервер улетит только одна ваша строка, а дальше вы уже будете ждать когда же все выполнится на сервере. До этого никаких данных вы слать на сервер не будете

Comment: Я вас уже спросил: вы рассматриваете подзапрос как запрос? Может, тут более широкий вопрос, просто вы его не задали?

Comment: Переформулирую. Забудем про отправку запроса на сервер и так понятно, что это один запрос. Как сервер воспримет данную конструкцию, как два запроса ?